# How to run Julia parallel code using distributed array computations (pre 1.x Julia versions)

Tags: julia

I am running on Windows the example from the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/#distributed-array-computations):

```rb
julia> function compute_something(A::DArray)
           B = darray(eltype(A), size(A), 3)
           for i = 1:size(A,3)
              @spawnat owner(B,i) B[:,:,i] = sqrt(A[:,:,i])
           end
           B
       end

julia> A = drand(10, 15, 4)

julia> compute_something(A)
```

But I get an error:

```rb
in compute_something: B not defined
```

Why I'm getting this error?

In [Web REPL](http://julia.forio.com) this example works.

Comment: I think this problem has been fixed:
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1482